# Why my text does not blink?

Tags: javascript

I want to blink my text using javascript but... nothing

```
var blocus = document.getElementById('blocus');
var cas = 1;

function changer() {
    if (cas == 1) {
        blocus.style.color = "rgb(58, 83, 155)";
        cas = 2;
    }
    if (cas == 2) {
        blocus.style.color = "rgb(154, 18, 179)";
        cas = 1;
    }
}

setInterval(changer, 100);
```

I don't understand why my text is not blinking infinite. Please help me. 
I want my text blink from a color to another color, and alternate, infinite....

Comment: 100 millisec is too fast.

Comment: No, even if I change it doesn't blink alternatively from a color to the other...

Comment: Please check you are running the JavaScript after the element exists. The second `if` will always be `true` as if the code path goes into the first `if`, it sets the conditions to pass the second. Combine with `else`

Comment: Please trace through your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `if (...) {...} else if (...) {...}` pattern instead of 2 `if` blocks.

For example, currently in your code if `cas === 1` then

1. The first `if` block changes `cas` to `2`.
2. The condition of the second `if` is then `cus === 2; // true`
3. The invocation goes into the second `if` block
4. The second `if` block overrides the change made by the first block

You therefore get no visible change in colour.

```
if (cas === 1) {
    blocus.style.color = "rgb(58, 83, 155)";
    cas = 2;
} else if (cas === 2) {
    blocus.style.color = "rgb(154, 18, 179)";
    cas = 1;
}
```

```js
var blocus = document.getElementById('blocus');
var cas = 1;

function changer() {
  if (cas === 1) {
    blocus.style.color = "rgb(58, 83, 155)";
    cas = 2;
  } else if (cas === 2) {
    blocus.style.color = "rgb(154, 18, 179)";
    cas = 1;
  }
}

setInterval(changer, 100);
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="blocus">
  hello
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/de2jgsuz/)

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```js
var blocus = document.getElementById('blocus');
var cas = false;

function changer() {
  cas = !cas;
    if (cas) {
        blocus.style.color = "rgb(58, 83, 155)";

    }else{
      blocus.style.color = "rgb(154, 18, 179)";
    }

}

setInterval(changer, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like so (adding an `else if` statement). Otherwise the second if will always be true.

```
function changer() {
    if (cas == 1) {
        blocus.style.color = "rgb(58, 83, 155)";
        cas = 2;
    } else if (cas == 2) {
        blocus.style.color = "rgb(154, 18, 179)";
        cas = 1;
    }
}
```